# CFSocket getting callbacks for other CFSocketContexts

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets

I am creating sockets and specifying a read callback like this:

```
// SocketUser.m     

...

- (void)run
{
    CFSocketContext context = {0, (__bridge void *)(self), NULL, NULL, NULL};
    CFSocketRef socket = CFSocketCreateWithNative(NULL, fd, kCFSocketReadCallBack, SocketReadCallback, &context);
}

static void SocketReadCallback(CFSocketRef s, CFSocketCallBackType type, CFDataRef address, const void *data, void *info)
{
    SocketUser* obj = (__bridge SocketUser *) info;

    [obj readData];
}

- (void)readData
{
    ...
}
```

In my application, there are multiple instances of SocketUser sending ICMP packets (the code is based on the SimplePing source from Apple).

The trouble is that each instance of SocketUser is receiving a read callback for every instance of SocketUser.  For example, if I have 5 instances and one of those instances receives a response, all 5 instances get a callback notification.  The "info" parameter can be inspected, but I don't really understand why I'm receiving callbacks for data received on other sockets.  I suppose I can just ignore callbacks from any context other than "self", but I'm kind of surprised to get the callbacks in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each TCP or UDP packet contains a port number, which the kernel uses to identify which socket should receive the packet's payload.

An ICMP echo response packet doesn't contain a port number.  The kernel has no way to decide which socket should receive the packet, so it just sends the packet to all open ICMP sockets.  So each of your `CFSocket` instances receives the packet, and each one calls `SocketReadCallback`.  There's no way to avoid that.  Your objects need to handle receiving unexpected ICMP packets.

Comment: Thank you.  I know that ICMP doesn't use ports but I guess I just improperly assumed that the kernel would match based on the identifier field in the ICMP header or something.  I suppose I'll use the identifier field myself.  Thank you for your response.